# When hystrix times out, how do you print the time it took?

Tags: java, hystrix

Whenever our code throws an exception that says `com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: MyClass timed-out and fallback failed.`, we always have to second guess ourselves as to whether or not the problem is that Hystrix is configured correctly.  An easy way we could answer that question would be if the log said how long it took for the Hystrix thread to run before it errored.  That way, if it says 1000ms, we know that Hystrix is not configured correctly (because that's the default) and if it says 5000ms, we know that it is configured the way we want.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
command.getExecutionTimeInMilliseconds()
```

this method tells you how many seconds your run method took, to capture in a timeout you can wrap this in a try catch inside your command class

```
 @Override
protected HttpResponse run() throws Exception {
    try {
        return executeSomeCall();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(getExecutionTimeInMilliseconds());
        throw e;
    }
}
```

or outside it on the invocation

```
try {
        HttpResponse response = command.execute();
        return response;
    }
    catch (HystrixRuntimeException e) {
        command.getExecutionTimeInMilliseconds() // do something with the info
    }
```

just one point, if you use Threads strategy its ok, but if you use Semaphor the timeout will only happen after you get a response. even that your timeout is 1000 ms and the request took 5000 ms. hystryx will wait 5000 ms to give you a timeout error and the getExecutionTimeInMilliseconds will return 1000 ms to you.